# Select single object from an Object Group

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

How do I fix this:

There are 2 objects in this group, 
one contains a name under 'Move-In (Name)', one doesn't:

```
$rest.Group | select * | Where-Object {$_.SERV_UNIT -eq '2704'}

Account_no                 : 12345
SERV_UNIT                  : 2704
FINALREAD                  : 
Move-In (Name)             : OWNER / CURRENT TENANT
Move-In (Home Phone #)     : 
Move-In (Business Phone #) : 
Move-In (Email)            : 

Account_no                 : 12345
SERV_UNIT                  : 2704
FINALREAD                  : 
CHANNEL_ID                 : 
Move-In (Name)             : 
Move-In (Home Phone #)     : 
Move-In (Business Phone #) : 
Move-In (Email)            :
```

I want to select only the one with a move in name.

However, with the code I've written, because they're apart of the same group, I will not pick up either:

```
$rest = $allinfo | Group-Object account_no | Where-Object { $_.Group.FINALREAD -contains '' -and $_.Group.'Move-In (Name)' -notcontains ''} | Select * -Unique
```

$rest now equals nothing. I want it to have one result, the first one with 'Owner' as the Move-in name.

To get the correct result I have to do this:

```
$rest = $allinfo | Group-Object account_no | Where-Object { $_.Group.FINALREAD -contains ''} | Select * -Unique 
$newRest = @()
foreach ($row in $rest.group) {

if ($row.'Move-In (Name)' -notcontains '')
{
    $newRest += $row 
}
}
```

Is it possible to do that all within this one line?

```
$rest = $allinfo | Group-Object account_no | Where-Object { $_.Group.FINALREAD -contains '' -and $_.Group.'Move-In (Name)' -notcontains ''} | Select * -Unique
```

If not, it's alright, I have an answer.

Thanks for help

Comment: And `$rest = $allinfo | Group-Object account_no | Where-Object { $_.Group.FINALREAD -contains '' -and $_.Group.'Move-In (Name)'} | Select * -Unique` does not work?

Comment: @Olaf, that will give me both results. I only one the one record, the one with the Owner / Tenant name, and the record without a name to be omitted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove the records you don't need (empty `Move-In`) first, then group by account and list the account-groups that contains one or more blank `FINALREAD`-values

```
$rest = $allinfo | Where-Object { $_.Group.'Move-In (Name)' } | Group-Object account_no | Where-Object { $_.Group.FINALREAD -contains '' }
```

Comment: This is because some accounts grouped have 2 or more records, and within, one of the accounts has no read. If one account has no read, then all of them need to go into $rest. Then after that, I must check for move-in name, because I don't want the records with no move-in name. Maybe I should be removing blank move-in names first

Comment: Remove as much as you can early on.

Comment: Lmao I'm an idiot. All I had to do is remove blank move-in names from when I'm creating $allinfo wow wow wow, how could I overlook something so simple. lmao